# MySQL query data retrieve giving everything null despite data in database

Tags: c#, mysql

so like my question said, I doing a mySQL query but the query is giving me some headache as I am trying to retrieve the data from my database as a object so I can reiterate in my javascript code however the data I retrieve out from the database is all null and 0 despite my database it self do not have value with null or 0. I have set my database value that it cannot be null.
So, this is the value in my database:
[image: You can ignore the null at the 3rd row cause it means nothing]

This is the data that I retrieved till.
`{"Musicid":0,"Audioid":null,"Description":null,"MusicTitle":null,"AudioPath":null,"ImagePath":null,"PriceType":null,"UploadDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","Views":0,"Likes":0,"NoOfReports":0,"Type":null}`

This is my C# class

```
public class music{
public int Musicid { get; set; }
public String Audioid { get; set; }
public String Description { get; set; }
public String MusicTitle { get; set; }
public String AudioPath { get; set; }
public String ImagePath { get; set; }
public String PriceType { get; set; }
public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
public int Views { get; set; }
public int Likes { get; set; }
public int NoOfReports { get; set; }
public String Type { get; set; }

public music(int musicid, String audioid, String description, String MusicTitle, String audioPath, String imagePath, String priceType, DateTime uploadDate, int views, int likes, int noOfreports, String Type)
{
    musicid = this.Musicid;
    audioid = this.Audioid;
    description = this.Description;
    MusicTitle = this.MusicTitle;
    audioPath = this.AudioPath;
    imagePath = this.ImagePath;
    priceType = this.PriceType;
    uploadDate = this.UploadDate;
    views = this.Views;
    likes = this.Likes;
    noOfreports = this.NoOfReports;
    Type = this.Type;
}
```

}

This is my c# code

```
public List<music> Searchdatabase(String searchvalue)
{
    List<music> al = new List<music>();
    ArrayList array = new ArrayList();

    //sql connection, query values to database error need help
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(cs))
    {

        con.Open();
        String query = "SELECT music.* FROM music WHERE MusicTitle LIKE @search";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "%" + searchvalue + "%");
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (searchvalue == null || searchvalue == "")
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    al.Add(new music(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(3), reader.GetString(4), reader.GetString(5), reader.GetString(6), reader.GetDateTime(7), reader.GetInt32(8), reader.GetInt32(9) , reader.GetInt32(10), reader.GetString(11)));
                }
            }

            if (reader != null)
                reader.Close();
        }

    }
    return al;
}
```

The command seems to be working just like whatever I key to the searchbox value which is for searchvalue like anything that not related to the musicTitle in the database will provided me with nothing which is correct. But anything that have relation to the musicTitle it return me the object array just that the value retrieved is null and 0 despite having data in database.

I know this may be lengthy, hopefully someone can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor code is wrong. You're assigning values to constructor parameters rather than the other way around.

```
public music(int musicid, String audioid, String description, String MusicTitle, String audioPath, String imagePath, String priceType, DateTime uploadDate, int views, int likes, int noOfreports, String Type)
{
    this.Musicid = musicid;
    ....
    this.NoOfReports = noOfreports;
    this.Type = Type;
}
```

Also, look into object initializers instead, so you don't write these ridiculous constructors.

```
new music { Musicid = musicid, Type, NoOfReports = noOfreports .... };
```

In this case you don't even need a constructor. As you can see, if the variable name is the same as the property name, you don't have to write this as `X = Y`, but just `X`. So it's like a constructor, but you don't have to write the actual constructor.

Comment: Good luck learning!
A debugger would've probably saved you a lot of time. Find how to debug on the platform you're developing.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor has everything in reverse order. You are setting the arguments instead of the properties. Change it to this and try again.

```
public music(int musicid, String audioid, String description, String MusicTitle, String audioPath, String imagePath, String priceType, DateTime uploadDate, int views, int likes, int noOfreports, String Type)
{
    this.Musicid =musicid;
    this.Audioid = audioid;
    this.Description = description;
    this.MusicTitle = MusicTitle;
    this.AudioPath = audioPath;
    this.ImagePath = imagePath;
    this.PriceType = priceType;
    this.UploadDate = uploadDate;
    this.Views = views;
    this.Likes = likes;
    this.NoOfReports = noOfreports;
    this.Type = Type;
}
```